# Partition of Real Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, real-numbers

Let R be the set of all real numbers. Is $\{\mathbb R^+,\mathbb R^−,\{0\}\}$ a partition of $\mathbb R$? Explain your answer.

My answer is no because of $\{0\}$. I am confused with $\{0\}$. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes because the union of 3 sets are $R$ and 3 sets are disjoint from each other. ${0}$ is just one point set of $0$.

Comment: One should also add that the sets belonging to the partition must be non-empty.

Comment: I just want to confirm, in {0}, there is only 1 point, 0.

Comment: yes, only one point.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, A set must be non- empty? Will it be ok if you give an example? I only two properties of sets belonging to a partition: 1) elements in S, based on you answer, must be included in a set in the partion, and 2) an element should not appear in more than one set.

Comment: @eLg : Suppose it were claimed that $\{\mathbb R^+,\mathbb R^-,\{0\},\varnothing\}$ is a partition.  That would be wrong because one of the four sets listed as members of the putative partition is empty. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Nonempty of set is presumed.

Answer (score 2):

It is a partition.  In order that $\{A, B, C\}$ be a partition of some set $S$, it is necessary and sufficient that

- $A\cup B\cup C=S$, and
- $A\cap B = B\cap C = A\cap C=\varnothing$, and
- $A$, $B$, and $C$ are non-empty.

And similarly for other numbers of sets than three.  (The second condition is that no two of the sets intersect; generally there would be more pairs of sets than there are sets when there are more than three sets.)

So yes, it is a partition.